# ToogleSwitch with 3 states for Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am looking for a ToogleSwitch control for Windows Phone 7 that has 3 states opposed to the current two states. I know about the Windows Phone 7 toolkit and it has a ToogleSwitch control, but it is having only 2 states. All tutorials, samples or hints how to customize the existing controls are welcome.

Comment: I would suggest starting from a checkbox which has the IsThreeState property (true|false|null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that starting from the toggle switch will be the easiest way.

It might be easier to:

- use 3 radio buttons - http://pocketnow.com/software-1/the-ui-controls-of-windows-phone-7-slider-push-and-radio-buttons-etc
- use a slider - http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Customizing-WP7-Slider-in-different-ways
- make up your own UserControl from a combination of 3 buttons or styled checkboxes.

Comment: thanks for the links. I extracted the ToggleSwitch template and it has a ToggleSwitchButton inside. I am going with that for now and trying to customize it for my own purposes. If everything is working then I will create my own custom control out of it.